# How to create Dockerfile for Cypress tests with Node.js server

Tags: node.js, docker, unit-testing, testing, cypress

I have my cypress tests, but also, I have some services that works with remote database and, most important, `Node.js` server that I need to send emails in case of error. The structure of project looks like this:

[image]

I have created `Dockerfile`, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
FROM cypress/included:9.4.1

WORKDIR /e2e-test

COPY package.json /e2e

RUN npm install

COPY . .

VOLUME [ "/e2e-test" ]

CMD ["npm", "run", "tests"]
```

So, what I need to do is mount this folder to docker container and then, by `npm run tests` run local server (**NOTE**: I need this local server only for `nodemailer`, because it works only on server side).

Also, script `npm run tests` looks like this. This script runs server and then tests - `"tests": "npm run dev & npx cypress run"`

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done this way:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM cypress/base:16.13.0

RUN mkdir /e2e-test

WORKDIR /e2e-test

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "tests"]
```

And start this using next command (in `Makefile`, for example): `docker run -it -v $PWD:/e2e-test -w /e2e-test e2e-tests`

This way, we can make work `node` server and make it send emails and at the same time, we will have mounted volume.